# Merge results with Async.Parallel without repeating expensive operation?

Tags: asynchronous, f#

Let's say I have a synchronous expensive operation:

```
let SomeExpensiveOp():string=
    System.Console.WriteLine"about to begin expensive OP"
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds 2.0)
    System.Console.WriteLine"finished expensive OP"
    "foo"
```

That I wrap as an async job:

```
let SomeExpensiveOpAs():Async<string>=async {
    return SomeExpensiveOp()}
```

Now I want to use this expensive operation to combine it with other two:

```
let SomeExpensiveOpSeq():seq<Async<string>>=
    let op = SomeExpensiveOpAs()
    seq {
        for some in [Bar(); Baz()] do
            yield async {
                let! prefix = op
                let! someAfterWaiting = some
                return (String.Concat (prefix, someAfterWaiting))
            }
    }
```

The purpose of putting it into a `seq<Async<'T>>` is to be able to use `Async.Parallel` this way:

```
let DoSomething() =
    let someAsyncOps = SomeExpensiveOpSeq() |> List.ofSeq
    let newOp = SomeExpensiveOpAs()
    let moreAsyncOps = (newOp::someAsyncOps)
    let allStrings = Async.RunSynchronously(Async.Parallel moreAsyncOps)
    for str in allStrings do
        Console.WriteLine str
    Console.WriteLine()
```

However, this makes `SomeExpensiveOp` to be executed three times. I would expect the second time to be executed an extra time because of the `newOp` call above, but I was expecting `SomeExpensiveOpSeq` to reuse the call to SomeExpensiveOp instead of calling it twice. How can I achieve SomeExpensiveOpSeq to only call SomeExpensiveOp once and reuse that for subsequent results?

Answer (score 2):

The key observation here is that `let!` is invoking the async expression every time—nothing caches its result. Consider this example where we have `expOp : Async<string>` but we *await* it three times in an `async` expression:

```
let expOp = SomeExpensiveOpAs()
async {
  let! a = expOp
  let! b = expOp
  let! c = expOp
  return [a;b;c]
} |> Async.RunSynchronously

about to begin expensive OP
finished expensive OP
about to begin expensive OP
finished expensive OP
about to begin expensive OP
finished expensive OP
val it : string list = ["foo"; "foo"; "foo"]
```

You can see the async *expensive op* gets evaluated each time. If you only want to execute that expensive operation once, you could fully evaluate/await its result and use that instead of awaiting it multiple times:

```
let SomeExpensiveOpSeq():seq<Async<string>>=
    let op = SomeExpensiveOpAs() |> Async.RunSynchronously
    seq {
        for some in [Bar(); Baz()] do
            yield async {
                let! someAfterWaiting = some
                return (String.Concat (op, someAfterWaiting))
            }
    }
```

This will still result in the expensive op being executed twice in your code—once in `SomeExpensiveOpSeq` and another as a result of being prepended on to `moreAsyncOps`—but it could be refactored further to a single invocation. Basically, if all subsequent async ops depend on this expensive evaluation, why not evaluate it once/first and then use its value wherever necessary:

```
let SomeExpensiveOpSeq op : seq<Async<string>>=
    seq {
        for some in [Bar(); Baz()] do
            yield async {
                let! someAfterWaiting = some
                return (String.Concat (op, someAfterWaiting))
            }
    }

let DoSomething() =
    let newOp = SomeExpensiveOpAs() |> Async.RunSynchronously
    let someAsyncOps = SomeExpensiveOpSeq newOp |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously
    let allStrings = newOp::(List.ofArray someAsyncOps)
    for str in allStrings do
        Console.WriteLine str
    Console.WriteLine()

> DoSomething();;
about to begin expensive OP
finished expensive OP
foo
foobar
foobaz
```

Comment: `why not evaluate it once/first and then use its value wherever necessary` because SomeExpensiveOp actually receives arguments, but maybe I simplified my example too much in the question